# Can Hybris Impexes allow for components migration and transformation into responsive components?

Tags: responsive, sap-commerce-cloud, mosaic, impex

Is it necessary to redo configurations entirely only to transform a given components which setup is stored into Hybris (such as checkout or signup) in order to make it responsive? (the target site being a mosaic theme adaptation)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if your requirement is clear to me. But sharing below just in case that's what you are looking for,

**Enable Responsive Behavior** - You would need to enable responsive behavior of your existing storefront by setting up following property in your *config/local.properties* file

```
commerceservices.default.desktop.ui.experience=responsive
```

**Customize theme/css** you can customize/manage the css theme by changing the available **.less** files

```
$mystorefront/web/webroot/WEB-INF/_ui-src/responsive/themes/
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: The case is that a site, in order to switch to responsive behavior, will fully redo the configuration of main components/features through HMC such as sign-up, add to cart, check-out, i.e basic e-commerce components. Mosaic Theme from Wordpress does dress up the site but the features come from Hybris (v6.3...) What I understand you are saying is that these Hybris features could be switched to responsive by enabling the ui.experience property in the config/local.properties file. Is that right?

Comment: Are you using hybris storefront extension with theme (css) from wordpress? If yes, then switching the property will solve your problem. (Assuming responsive css files are placed at expected directory in less file format)

Comment: I am researching this, with adecuate actors, might take a while, but from what I read I understand that extension can easily be added if not the case yet...?

Comment: Indeed. If you started with a recipe or modulegen command, it must already be available in your localextensions.xml file. And if you're using it separately, then you can access services through OCC services.

Comment: Hope you are able to figure it out. Good luck!